# downloading file from google drive using api( NameError: name 'service' is not defined)

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-api-python-client

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    results = service.files().list(
        pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
    items = results.get('files', [])

    if not items:
        print('No files found.')
    else:
        print('Files:')
        for item in items:
            print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

save as quickstart.py and run this file , The authentication flow has completed.
then token.json was generated in the directory.
now to download doc file

```
file_id = '1wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0'
request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
fh = io.BytesIO()
downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
done = False
while done is False:
    status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
    print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))
```

id was copied from 
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0/edit?usp=sharing

and request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

change to

request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)

in the example as saved as p.py
when executed

```
line 2, in <module>
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
NameError: name 'service' is not defined
```

Comment: you have to define the service function like:
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

It was defined inside a main() function. The other functions do not know what 'service' is.

Comment: where to add  service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

Comment: inside the function you are using it in

Comment: without merge two file,(quickstart.py) and (download.py)  here download.py 1st line above file_id service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))  got NameError: name 'build' is not defined

Comment: on merging both py file and adding line before file_id after else statement got NameError: name 'io' is not defined

Comment: so new error? it means my suggestion about 'service' worked

Answer (score 1):

I am going to have to assume you have not merged these two files. THe second script needs the service (variable) within your first script to run they should be merged.

```
from __future__ import print_function
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'

def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    store = file.Storage('token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    if not creds or creds.invalid:
        flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('credentials.json', SCOPES)
        creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
    service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

    # Call the Drive v3 API
    rfile_id = '1wzCjl51u131v1KBgpbiKLJs8DPPakhXCFosfYjp7BY0'
    request = service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    fh = io.BytesIO()
    downloader = MediaIoBaseDownload(fh, request)
    done = False
    while done is False:
        status, done = downloader.next_chunk()
        print ("Download %d%%." % int(status.progress() * 100))    

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: line 23, in main
    fh = io.BytesIO()
NameError: name 'io' is not defined  , there was spelling mistake rfile_id , i changed to file_id

Comment: The docstring says "Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to." This code does NOT do that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I do it

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file
​
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly']
​
​
def login_gdrive(SCOPES):
    store = file.Storage('../personal_token.json')
    creds = store.get()
    return build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))
​
def gdrive_download(file_id):
    request = drive_service.files().get(fileId=file_id)
    result = request.execute()

    #will return metadata of file but I will only get file name
    file_name = result['name']
    print(f"File name is {file_name}")

    #will get actual file
    request = drive_service.files().get_media(fileId=file_id)
    result = request.execute()
    print("Downloading " + file_name)

    #will write file using the file_name
    with open(file_name, mode="wb") as f:
        f.write(result)
    print("Finished writing " + file_name)
​
drive_service = login_gdrive(SCOPES)
​
gdrive_download('1oiD6h-ixAUTIWebEdN-jV8MO0sssoQTI')


out...  File name is sample_data_2018-10-21.csv
out...  Downloading sample_data_2018-10-21.csv
out...  Finished writing sample_data2018-10-21.csv
```